# Notepad++: remove all border-radius in my css

Tags: notepad++, css

I'm trying to understand how to remove all the border-radius' in my css file. The format is:

```
border-radius: *px;
```

But I tried with every combination of * and . and couldn't get it to work. The count is always 0.

**EDIT**

I should have specified, I already have about 50 border-radii specified in my code! But I decided I didn't want them anymore, I would like to use Notepad++ to remove them all from the .css file!

Comment: What do you mean count is always 0?

Comment: You will probably have to use a regex within the find and replace.

Comment: @Jet, this isn't a SO question! And that's not how you get posts moved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on Regular Expression searching, then search for `border-radius: [0-9]+px;`

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, select `Regular Expression` in the *Search Mode* options and search for something like

> border-radius: ?(?:\d+px|0);

Leave the *Replace with* field empty and you should be fine. If every rule is on a new line you might want to add `\r\n` at the end of the regular expression to prevent empty lines.